# How to use http.ResponseWriter in fasthttp for executing HTML templates etc.?

Tags: go

I've recently moved from golang net/http to fasthttp owing to rave reviews.

As you know, fasthttp doesn't use (w http.ResponseWriter) but only one syntax which is (ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx).

I tried using ctx.Write but it didn't work.

So, how can I implement http.ResponseWriter in the code below to excute my html templates? Please also give some explanation so that we could all benefit.

Much Thanks for your help!

```
package main()

import (
    "html/template"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
    )


type PageData struct {
    Title     string
    }   


func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("public/templates/*.html"))
}

m := func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {

    switch string(ctx.Path()) {

        case "/":
        idx(ctx)

        default:
        ctx.Error("not found", fasthttp.StatusNotFound)
    }
}

fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":8081", m)
}

func idx(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {

    pd := new(PageData)
    pd.Title = "Index Page"

    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(ctx.write, "index.html", pd)
    if err != nil {
    log.Println("LOGGED", err)
    http.Error(ctx.write, "Internal server error",      http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
```

}

Comment: `template.Execute` doesn't have anything to do with `http.ResponseWriter`, it takes any `io.Writer`.

Comment: You might consider sticking to the standard library until you have a firm grasp of Go and the standard library, before looking at replacing it with third-party solutions. It will make it much easier to learn and get help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*fasthttp.RequestCtx` implements the `io.Writer` interface (that's why `ctx.Write()` exists), which means that you can simply pass `ctx` as the parameter to `ExecuteTemplate()`:

```
tpl.ExecuteTemplate(ctx, "index.html", pd)
```

Also, the `http.Error()` call will not work, since `RequestCtx` is not a `http.ResponseWriter`. Use the `RequestCtx`'s [own error function](https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/fasthttp#RequestCtx.Error) instead:

```
ctx.Error("Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
```